# How to set a selected option in a select element using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have seen many questions about this, but none seems to be working for me. I have been trying to test it on the chrome developer tools, but nothing. This is my select element:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="10">Something</option>
  <option value="11">Something2</option>
</select>
```

Now I am trying to set it like so:

```
$('#select option[value="11"]').prop("selected", true)
```

Now I have also tried using the `attr` method, but also does not work. I should mention this is a simplified example and my list has hundreds of options. The end goal is to set a new selected item and reflect it on the web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `$("#mySelect").val(11)`.  `$("#mySelect")` will select `<select>` tag from DOM which has id **mySelect** and using `.val(11)` will set the option tag of select as select which has **value** attribute equal to 11:

```
$("#mySelect").val(11);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mySelect').val(11)
```

try this